# Wrong relative paths with Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a index.html with a relative path. I need it to be this path:

```
<script defer type="module" src="Basis_24.2.0.0/js/WZP-React-24.2.0.0.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script defer type="module" src="./Basis_24.2.0.0/js/WZP-React-24.2.0.0.js"></script>
```

I have marked it as external. I have tried adding base "./" and when i do that it ends up as

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="./WZP-React-24.2.0.0.js"></script>
```

this is my vite config for this:

```
                base: './',
                plugins: [react()],
                build: {
                    rollupOptions: {
                        external: ['Basis_24.2.0.0/js/WZP-React-24.2.0.0.js'],
                    }
                }
```

Set external.
Set base as adviced on vite docs.
Tried different combination but with base "./" it only keeps src after last slash...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using:

```
renderBuiltUrl(filename, { hostId, hostType, type }) {
     return path + filename;
}
```